# Jquery ajax change class clicked by data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

i have one question about jquery on click.

This is **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7qq4c9h2/2/)** from jsfiddle.net

When you click the demo you can see there is a green and yellwo div.

The question is when you click the `data-id="1"` and change this div class:

```
<div class="icon-kr icon-globe"></div>
```

change `icon-globe` to `icon-contacs`

and when you click `data-id="2"` then change:

change `icon-globe` to `icon-lock-1`

also same think is for `data-id="0"`
How can i do that anyone can help me in this regard ?
HTML

```
<div class="container" id="1">
    <div class="icon_ar"><div class="icon-kr icon-globe"></div>1</div>
    <div class="pr_type">
        <div class="type_s change_pri" data-id="0"><div class="icon-pr icon-globe"></div>1</div>
        <div class="type_s change_pri" data-id="1"><div class="icon-pr icon-contacs"></div>2</div>
        <div class="type_s change_pri" data-id="2"><div class="icon-pr icon-lock-1"></div>3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.change_pri').click(function(){
    var dataid = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var id = $(this).closest('.container').attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "chage_number.php",
        data: { dataid : dataid, id: id }
    }).success(function(result){
        alert(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you specify the question better?I am having a hard time understanding it\

Comment: I don't understand your problem too, but it is most likely you can try `$('body').on('click', 'selector', function() {});`  it will bind the event to dynamically created html.

Comment: @Varun i edited the question i understood why you can not understand because i write wrong data id before. Now the id is correct. Please check it again for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is below. I have only done the class changing bit based on click. I am not sure about your ajax code. Let me know if you need further help.

```
$('.change_pri').click(function(){

    var class_name = $(this).find(".icon-pr").attr("class");
    class_name = class_name.replace(/icon\-pr\s+/gi, "");
    $(this).closest(".container").find(".icon-kr")
    .removeClass().addClass("icon-kr " + class_name);
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qq4c9h2/5/)

Comment: Very clean answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: can i ask you something about your answer. What is the `/gi` ?

Comment: They are RegExp flags. Take a [look at this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for more info. In your case, you don't need them as we're looking at the class name with definite case and only one occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use .data(), you are not accessing the data correctly.
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

```
var dataid = $(this).data('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing this data-* attribute incorrectly,
Use this,

```
$('.change_pri').click(function(){
    var dataid = $(this).data('id');
        $(this).parent().siblings('.icon_ar').find('div').removeClass("icon-globe icon-contacs icon-lock-1");
        if(dataid=="0")
        {
             $(this).parent().siblings('.icon_ar').find('div').addClass("icon-globe");
        }
        else if(dataid==1)
        {
             $(this).parent().siblings('.icon_ar').find('div').addClass("icon-contacs");
        }
        else
        {
             $(this).parent().siblings('.icon_ar').find('div').addClass("icon-lock-1");
        }


//AJAX CODE.
    });
```

Comment: @innovation There are some parts in this left static,you can change it to your needs!